# Windows 10 Mobile Apps to Work With Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile

We're about to migrate our Windows Phone 8.1 app into Windows 10 Mobile.

Is there any way to keep them working with WP8.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your app to Windows 10 Mobile this version won't work on 8.1. The dev center allows you to manage two (or more) app versions for different SDK levels, but you'll need to manage two codebases.